# Porting C++ and c# projects from visual studio 2013 to vs 2017

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2017, installshield-2012

I am porting C# and CPP projects from  Visual Studio 2013 , Windows 7 platform  to Visual Studio 2017[.Net Framework 4.6.2] Windows 10 platform.

This has produced an installer using installshield 2012 with binaries from vs 2017 build.

But while running this installer the system is requesting to  install .NET Framework 3.5. We had verified the dll's using .net reflector and the dll's do have 4.6.2 framework version. **Why does it require 3.5?**

attaching the screenshot[image]

Comment: Might be a problem with InstallShield... try copying binaries manually, install the C++ runtime corresponding to the C++ toolchain version (VS2017 supports several), and see if you still get the error.

Comment: "porting" from C# to C#. Why?